# None of my print statements are appearing in the Xcode console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I have created this function called `createTeams()` which is creating data for the table.

```
func createTeams() {
    let team1 = teams(Team1: "Chelsea", Team2: "Arsenal" , startTime: "15/06/2019", location: "London")
    let team2 = teams(Team1: "Barcelona", Team2: "Manchester" , startTime: "16/06/2019", location: "London")
    let team3 = teams(Team1: "Real Madrid", Team2: "FC Bayern" , startTime: "17/06/2019", location: "London")
    let team4 = teams(Team1: "Chelsea", Team2: "Juvantis" , startTime: "18/06/2019", location: "London")
    let team5 = teams(Team1: "LiverPool", Team2: "FC Dallas" , startTime: "19/06/2019", location: "London")
    let team6 = teams(Team1: "Atlanta FC", Team2: "NewCastle Utd." , startTime: "20/06/2019", location: "London")

    teamsList.append(team1)
    teamsList.append(team2)
    teamsList.append(team3)
    teamsList.append(team4)
    teamsList.append(team5)
    teamsList.append(team6)
}
```

I call this function in `viewDidLoad` and it works fine.

However, I have this `print` statement in `viewDidLoad` that doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Awake");

    self.createTeams()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

I Even have this button with a simple print statement that is not working either.

```
@IBAction func subscribeButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Subscribe Button Clicked")

    if(isSubscribed) {
        print("User Subscribed to this ");
        isSubscribed = false
    } else {
        print("User Unsubbed");
        isSubscribed = true
    }
}
```

---

> Edit: It is a watchKit Project i am developing so it was loading from
>   the watch Interface and printing from there in order to print those
>   statements i had to run the project on a iPhone simulator individually

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need those semicolons (`;`).

Comment: i have `subscribeButtonClicked` that has print statement without `;` that doesn't work either

Comment: At the bottom of the console area, what is your Output pop-up menu set to? If it's set to `Debugger Output`, that prevents me from seeing my apps logging calls, but with `All Output`, I can see them. Additionally, if you have a string entered in the `Filter` search field that can't be found in the output, that would essentially eliminate any displayed output.

Comment: @NSGod Still no luck. thnx for the suggestion Anyways

Comment: Did you connect your view controller from the storyboard to this custom view controller file?

Comment: Try adding breakpoints and see if the control reaches there. Try print statements in the Playground just to check if you are doing everything properly. If you still are not able to find the problem, try creating a new fresh project just in case, that helps some times.

Answer (score 11):

So after doing a lot of research and following the previous steps mentioned about the console not showing it turned out that I've hid the console area or deactivated it.
To activate/show it :

1. Hover to "View" in the top menu in Xcode
2. Tap "Debug Area"
3. Choose "Activate Console"

or simply click command+shift+c

Answer (score 2):

The problem is sometimes xcode debugger crashed due to some internal inconsistency or for other reasons. So what we write print statements cannot be shown in debugger window.

You need to do these steps:

1. Clean the xcode.
2. Force quit the xcode.
3. Clean the derieved data.
4. Restart the xcode and run it.

It will work fine.